# Why the return value in closure didn't cover the binded one in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is my code in Swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Contentview: View {
@State private var numberOfPeople = 2
 Section {
    Picker("Number of Person", selection: $numberOfPeople) {
           ForEach(2..<10) {
               Text("\($0) people")
            }
     }
                   
    Text("\(numberOfPerson) people")
   }


}
```

Number of people should be at least 2, and with a max of 10.
I bind the value`numberOfPeople` in `Picker`, and I show the value `numberOfPeople` in `Text`, but the actual value of `numberOfPeople` are alway 2 less than the value I shown in `Picker`

[image: Check out this picture]

Comment: Well is it numberOfPerson or numberOfPeople?

Comment: And try adding `id: \.self` to your ForEach and see if that helps.

Comment: Please make some effort to post that compiles

Comment: Unrelated but *at least 2, and with a max of 10* is `2..<11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Approach:

- You are not tagging your views
- You need to add `tag($0)`

## Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var numberOfPerson = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Picker("Number of Person", selection: $numberOfPerson) {
                ForEach(2..<10) {
                    Text("\($0) people")
                        .tag($0) //Fix
                }
            }
            
            Text("\(numberOfPerson) people")
        }
    }
}
```